# Como fazer funcionar jquery click com Scroll infinito?

Tags: php, html, jquery, rolamento, click

Tenho a pagina inicial com uma lista de coisas:

```
<table id="table" class="tabela" >
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th class="check">V</th>
            <th class="nivel">N</th>
            <th class="item">Item</th>
            <th class="item2">item2</th>
            <th class="item3">item3</th>
            <th class="item4">item4</th>
            <th class="item5">item5</th>
            <th class="item6">item6</th>
            <th class="icone">PT</th>
            <th class="icone">IT</th>
            <th class="icone">JT</th>
            <th class="icone">DXF</th>
            <th class="icone">RAR</th>
            <th class="icone">ZIP</th>
            <th class="icone">EPJ</th>
            <th class="formulario">Form.</th>
            <th class="comentario">C.</th>
            <th class="endereco">Endereço</th>
            <th class="data">Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
    include 'banco_configuracao/config.php';
    $rowperpage = 100;
    $sql = "select * from LISTA2  order by cast(REFERENCIAGERAL as int) offset 0 rows fetch next $rowperpage rows only ";
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) { ?>            
        <tr style = "background-color: <?php echo $row["CORDEFUNDO"]?>; color: <?php echo $row["CORDETEXTO"]?>">
            <td class = "check" id = "<?php echo $row["REFERENCIAGERAL"]?>">
                <input onclick = "passaValor(this.id)" class = "largerCHECKBOX" type = "CHECKBOX" id = "<?php echo $row["REFERENCIAGERAL"]?>" <?php echo $row["CHECKBOX"] ?> name="">
            </td>                
            <td class="nivel" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_nivel ?>"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"]; if ($row['NIVEL'] != NULL) {echo $row['NIVEL'];} else {echo 'vazio';} echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
            <td class="item" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_item ?>"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"]; if ($row["NUMERO_ITEM"] != NULL) {echo $row['REFERENCIAGERAL'];} else {echo 'vazio';} echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
            <td class="material"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"];echo $row['MATERIAL']; echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
            <td class="descricao"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"]; echo utf8_encode($row['DESCRICAO']); echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
            <td class="qtd_eng"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"]; echo $row['QTDENG']; echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td><td class="qtd_falt"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"]; echo $row['QTDFALT']; echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
            <?php
            if ($row["OBSERVACAO"] != ' ') {
                $visibilidade = "visible";
            } else {
                $visibilidade = "hidden";
            }?>

            <td class="obs" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade ?>"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"];if ($row["OBSERVACAO"] != ' ') { echo utf8_encode($row['OBSERVACAO']); } else {echo "hey";} echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
            <td class="icone" id="<?php echo $row["PDF_PT"] ?>" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_pdf ?>"><img src="<?php if ($row["LINK_TCD_LINK_PDF_PT_IMAGE"] != NULL) { echo $row["LINK_TCD_LINK_PDF_PT_IMAGE"]; } else {echo 'icones/pdfbr.png';} ?>" width="30"></td>
            <td class="icone" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_it ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $row["PDF_IT"] ?>" target="_blank"><img src="<?php if ($row["LINK_TCD_LINK_PDF_IT_IMAGE"] != NULL) {echo $row["LINK_TCD_LINK_PDF_IT_IMAGE"];} else {echo 'icones/pdfit.png';} ?>" width="30"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="icone" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_jt ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $row["LINK_JT"] ?>"target="_blank"><img src="<?php if ($row["LINK_TCD_LINK_JT_IMAGE"] != NULL) {echo $row["LINK_TCD_LINK_JT_IMAGE"];} else {echo 'icones/linkjt.png';} ?>" width="30"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="icone" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_dxf ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $row["LINK_DXF"] ?>"target="_blank"><img src="<?php if ($row["LINK_TCD_LINK_DXF_IMAGE"] != NULL) {echo $row["LINK_TCD_LINK_DXF_IMAGE"];} else {echo 'icones/dxf.png';} ?>" width="30"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="icone" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_rar ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $row["LINK_RAR"] ?>"target="_blank"><img src="<?php if ($row["LINK_TCD_LINK_RAR_IMAGE"] != NULL) {echo $row["LINK_TCD_LINK_RAR_IMAGE"];} else {echo 'icones/rar.png';} ?>" width="30"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="icone" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_zip ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $row["LINK_ZIP"] ?>"target="_blank"><img src="<?php if ($row["LINK_TCD_LINK_ZIP_IMAGE"] != NULL) {echo $row["LINK_TCD_LINK_ZIP_IMAGE"];} else {echo 'icones/zip.png';} ?>" width="30"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="icone" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_epj ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $row["LINK_EPJ"] ?>"target="_blank"><img src="<?php if ($row["LINK_TCD_LINK_EPJ_IMAGE"] != NULL) {echo $row["LINK_TCD_LINK_EPJ_IMAGE"];} else {echo 'icones/epj.png';} ?>" width="30"></a>
            </td>
            <td class="formulario" id="<?php echo $row["REFERENCIAGERAL"] ?>">
                <input type="image" title="Formulários" id="<?php echo $row["REFERENCIAGERAL"] ?>" src="imagens/forms.png" name="" width="30" >
            </td>
            <td class="comentario" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_comentario ?>"><img src="icones/comentario.png" width="30" id="<?php echo $row["REFERENCIAGERAL"] ?>"></td>
            <td class="endereco" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_endereco ?>"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"];if ($row['ENDERECO_ENTREGA'] != NULL) {echo $row['ENDERECO_ENTREGA'];} else {echo 'hey';} echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
            <td class="data" style="visibility: <?php echo $visibilidade_data ?>"><?php echo $row["FORMATACAO"]; echo $row['PRODUCAOPCP_DATA_DE_REMESSA'];echo $fecha_formatacao; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

tenho um jquery que carrega a proxima pagina. O scroll infinito funciona perfeitamente. No entanto ao clicar no td com jquery abro um modal com o id do item clicado e isso nao funciona quando estou na outra pagina php.
A outra pagina php contem a continuação da lista, é ela que carrega os demais dados. Quanto os primeiros 100 itens chegam ao fim carrega-se mais uma pagina;

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método .on();

```
$('div').on('click', function()
{
    //evento
});
```